# Jasper Report giving java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have made report using Jasper report ireport. and it is generating successfully on my laptop. but when i deploy same jar file to other computer then generating report then it will give the error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXMLoader.java:248)
```

i have put the all the jar file related to jasper at the same location where it place on my laptop. but it gives same error.

The code :

```
public class JasperReport {
    public void generateReport(int invoiceNumber, String fileName) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = ConnectDB.openConnection();
            net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport jasperReport;
            try (InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("report1_1.jrxml")) {
                System.out.println("Hello "+JasperReport.class.getResource("report1_1.jrxml").getFile().toString());
                JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
                jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            }
           Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           map.put("invoiceNumber", invoiceNumber);
           JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, connection);

           File fileReportName = new File(fileName);
           OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileReportName);
           JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
           outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(JasperReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
                ConnectDB.closeConnection();
            }

    }

        public static void generateStockReport(String fileName) {
        try {
            String userName = "root";
        String password = "pass";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/JindalEnterprises";
        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
        Connection connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection ( url, userName , password );

            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            workingDir=workingDir+"/src/com/jindal/reports/report1_1.jrxml";
          classPath=report.getClass().getResource("JasperReport.class").getPath();
            System.out.println(workingDir);
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(workingDir));
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
            net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            inputStream.close();
           JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, connection);

           File fileReportName = new File(fileName);
           OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileReportName);
           JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
           outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JasperReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the output of System.out.println("Hello "+JasperReport.class.getResource("report1_1.jrxml").getFile().toString());?

Comment: output : Hello file:/C:/Document%and%settings/mypc/Desktop/JindalEnterprises.jar!/com/jindal/reports/report1_1.jrxml

Comment: this is the output of my laptop and its working fine on my laptop when i deploy the same on other laptop then that line had not print.

Comment: Looks like report1_1.jrxml is not in your classpath. Can you inspect the contents of the jar file and see if report1_1.jrxml is included in it?

Comment: i have hard code the location of .jasper file in jrxml file. i have put all the jrxml and jasper file in c drive folder

Comment: How are you executing the jar file? Are you providing the classpath?

Comment: i have execute the jar file on cmd as java -jar JindalEnterprises.jar

Comment: Try using the -cp flag and provide the path to report1_1.jrxml. For ex: if report1_1.jrxml is in C:\temp, try java -cp C:\temp\ -jar JindalEnterprises.jar.

Comment: Basically the problem is that the code will find the report1_1.jrxml and when it exceute the line  JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);

Comment: it will give error msg